# Unable to upload an empty file in google cloud when doing resumable upload in ReactJS . it's showing CORS Error

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage

**Below is My Request Header , access-control-allow-origin is already set to * in Request Header as shown below but still CORS Error is coming (it's coming only when trying to upload a empty file)**

```
:authority: storage.googleapis.com
:method: PUT
:path: /sms-local-bucket/3f9e2365-8d03-40e2-9635-a3d1860a7f23/8a70f7a3-59ff-4d36-b0ce-8e32efe55493?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=sfs-local%40revbits-sfs-local.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20211029%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20211029T034429Z&X-Goog-Expires=61&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost%3Bx-goog-resumable&X-Goog-Signature=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&upload_id=ADPycdtHTqXlDLRx1GxLY6W3FsJHuxT0VJJNqtdPpQ3DxlfS8TvCeTjOFhDSTQCsrb2VMGgnAER1CPNOStNV2Uus4WSTJpzsGQ
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 0
content-range: bytes 0--1/0
content-type: application/octet-stream
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
x-client-data: CJG2yQEIorbJAQipncoBCO/yywEInvnLAQjnhMwBCPqEzAEItYXMAQjLicwB
Decoded:
message ClientVariations {
  // Active client experiment variation IDs.
  repeated int32 variation_id = [3300113, 3300130, 3313321, 3340655, 3341470, 3342951, 3342970, 3343029, 3343563];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you  share the CORS error what you are getting either as screenshot or copy paste the error here.

Comment: @PriyankaKharche sure , i have attached the Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you create the application in localhost header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and if it is not working, install the CORS Everywhere plugin in your browser and then check the response and it will work fine.

Plugin URL :

For Firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/
For Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Also, Chrome does not support localhost for CORS requests (an error opened since 2010) [1], if you inspect the thread of this error.

For more information on CORS, please refer to the following document[2].

[1] https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors

Comment: I hope this answer helped you.